# Windows 7: Credential Manager looses stored credentials after restart

Tags: windows-7, credentials-manager

Since couple of months my laptop (Windows 7 Professional SP 1) forgets its credentials after restart. it bothers me a lot I need to fill in all passwords again and again in work environment.

So before I restart my machine, all credentials are stored in Credential Manager. After restart the credentials are gone.

How can I fix this?